# Create sockets in Python from PHP

Tags: python, php, sockets

First of all, thank you for taking time to read and help me !

I have a huge code in PHP, composed of a lot of functions.
I want to migrate these functions in Python. It will take time, but I want to use my new Python functions during the migration.

So I want my PHP to execute migrated functions in Python.
When a request is received, I execute a script in Python which create sockets :

> one control socket : which will receive command as Execute, flush, or close all socket
> one datas socket : which receive the function name and the arguments

Here is the code in PHP, this function is called during the initialization :

```
public function initializeSockets() {
        $script = "python sockets.py"
        $descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin est un pipe où le processus va lire
            1 => array("pipe", "w"), // stdout est un fichier pour écrire
            2 => array("pipe", "w")  // stderr est un fichier pour écrire
        );
        $process = proc_open($script, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

        if (is_resource($process)) {
            stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0); // Set STDOUT non-blocking
            stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0); // Set STDERR non-blocking

            $output = "";
            $found = false;

            while (!$found) {
                $read = fread($pipes[1], 8192);
                $output .= $read;
                if (strpos($read, "1") !== false) {
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }
                usleep(100000); // Attente pour réduire la charge du CPU
            }

            fclose($pipes[0]);
            fclose($pipes[1]);
            fclose($pipes[2]);
            proc_close($process);
        }
```

And here is the python script :

```
import sys
import os

import socket
import threading
import re
import asyncio

ctrl_port = None
data_port = None
used_ports = []

try:
    if os.name == "nt":
        sys.path.insert(0, 'C:' + os.sep + 'git' + os.sep + 'SMARTCrane' + os.sep)
        from config.alchemy.system.paths        import *
        from src.Alchemy.RestBehavior           import *
    elif os.name == "posix":
        sys.path.insert(0, 'opt' + os.sep + 'backend' + os.sep + 'airflow' + os.sep + 'dags' + os.sep + 'Alchemy' + os.sep)
        from config.system.paths                import *
        from src.Alchemy.RestBehavior           import *
except ImportError as e:
    toolsLog(f"Erreur lors de l'importation dans {__file__}: {e}")


def find_unused_port():
    global used_ports
    ports = range(12000, 12999)
    for port in ports:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            unused = True
            if s.connect_ex(('localhost', port)) == 0 or port in used_ports:
                used_ports.append(port)
                unused = False
            if unused:
                used_ports.append(port)
                return port
    raise RunTimeError("No unused port found in the range 12000-12999")


async def handle_ctrl_socket(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = await reader.read(1)
        if data.decode() == "C":
            break
    writer.close()

async def handle_data_socket(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = await reader.read(100)


async def main():
    global ctrl_port, data_port

    ctrl_port = find_unused_port()
    data_port = find_unused_port()
    
    print(f"PID:{os.getpid()},ctrl:{ctrl_port},data:{data_port}")

    data_socket = await asyncio.start_server(handle_data_socket, '127.0.0.1', data_port)
    ctrl_socket = await asyncio.start_server(handle_ctrl_socket, '127.0.0.1', ctrl_port)

    async with ctrl_socket, data_socket:
        await asyncio.gather(
            ctrl_socket.serve_forever(),
            data_socket.serve_forever()
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

But, the command proc_open block the execution of the request
My goal is to get the PID, and the two ports of the sockets..

Is someone sees a problem in my code ? I have tried a lot of ideas, IA and forums helps me but I can't find a solution...

Thank you again for your time,
Nicolas

Comment: what do you mean by `the command proc_open block the execution of the request`, is there an error?

Comment: Hello, 
No there is no error
But the python script is infinite, to allow socket to listen the ports

Since I execute the Python script from PHP, even if I use proc_open, the request is executing indefinitely.. 

I tried to write in a file the informations I want : PID, and ports : 
 with open('python_scripts_output.txt', "w") as file:
        file.write(f"PID:{os.getpid()},ctrl:{ctrl_port},data:{data_port}")
I put it next to the print() 
And it works

If I don't execute the python script, the PHP request works fine

Comment: can you calrify 2 things here `it works If I don't execute the python script`, does the Python script run properly without PHP? And, can you check the return value or have error logging and see where the issue is actually?

Comment: Instead of all those concatenations with `os.sep`, use `os.path.join()` or `pathlib`.